# How to modularize Javascript authentication code in MFE context in a VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, azure-ad-msal, micro-frontend

I'm working on a large,single-page VueJS application that's been broken down into several micro front-ends, and I'm currently implementing the authentication for communication with the orchestration layer and it's stumping me. The application is organized as a container application that bootstraps and mounts several other VueJS applications underneath it using single-spa

We use Azure-AD and the MSAL library for authentication and to refresh the Bearer token before each API request, and currently the application I'm working had previously stored the AD client info itself and created the authenticationContext on initialization, something like

```js
export class Authentiation {
  authenticationContext;
  refreshToken;
  constructor() {
    this.authenticationContext = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)
    // code to initialize the 
  }
  async acquireToken() {
    // code which refreshes the token
  }
}
```

Now, the initial authentication code has been moved into the container application since it will authenticate the user first and only then mount the apps once the user is inside. Each application, though, needs to be able to refresh the Bearer token whenever it communicates with its OL layer. Currently, it's just running the initialization again and pulling the AuthenticationContext out of local storage using the supplied keys

The goal is to modify it so that a the authentication context from the container is passed down to whatever application is being mounted up, without the need to store the AD client and context information in the app itself

What's required is that every repository within the application would have an API object injected into it, and would use this API when making requests, and the API would contain the authentication context for being able to refresh the Bearer token on each call, and this is where I'm stumped

I had thought about creating an Authentication Singleton that the API could use when being injected into a repository, but since the authenticationContext is unknown at the time, it feels weird to set it after the fact, ie something like

```js
let authContext = new Authentication()

// setup single-spa bootstrap code
// this function is called when the container application bootstraps this Vue application
export const bootstrap = (props) => 
  vueLifecycles.bootstrap(props).then(async () => {
    authContext.setContext(props.authentication)
  })
```

Then when the API gets intialized, it would have an authContext that would invoke authContext.acquireToken() to get a Bearer token to set for each refresh. But, something feels incorrect about doing this way and I'm not 100% if it's the way to go.

To summarize, applications that were once handling authentication on their own are now being passed the authentication context as a prop during load, and I'm confused about how to implement this to properly set this context as part of the API

Another team had actually stored the acquireToken function in the a Vuex store but that, to me, does not seem appropriate since it ties this code specifically to Vue